# group rows based on a column codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to group rows based on a column .I attached my table
I tried,my problem is that,when using group_by,it wil return only one row of each user. i want  whole data from this table group by user_id
Model

```
 public function get_pdf_print( $start_date, $end_date) {
          $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('jil_invoices');
   $this->db->group_by('jil_invoices.inv_userid');
  $this->db->where('jil_invoices.inv_dated >=', $start_date);
        $this->db->where('jil_invoices.inv_dated <=', $end_date);
  $query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

[image: this is my table structure]

Comment: first of all make discussion what u need? if you want to use group by userid than it will retrun one record for each user, if you want to get all rows than you can't use groupby with userid

Comment: please give a brief on your question..

Comment: i know it wil not get by group_by. so if anybody knows please help

Comment: @devpro i know it wil not get by group_by. so if anybody knows please help

Comment: i suggest u to get all records than use php for grouping

Comment: @devpro how using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `GROUP BY` with userid column than note that it will not return the all rows.

I suggest you to get all rows and than use PHP for grouping purpose something like:

**In your Model:**

```
public function get_pdf_print($start_date, $end_date) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('jil_invoices');
    $this->db->where('jil_invoices.inv_dated >=', $start_date);
    $this->db->where('jil_invoices.inv_dated <=', $end_date);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array(); // here i am using result_array function will return result into array.
}
```

**In your controller:**

```
$records = $this->model_yourmodel->get_pdf_print($startDate,$endDate);
$userData = array();
foreach ($records as $key => $value) {
    $userData[$value['inv_userid']][] = $value; // get all record against each user
}
```

Comment: where is the condition to select data based on user id

Comment: @saleena: no need to used userid in where.. do u want to get specific user data?

Comment: @saleena: than it will work, get all records and in your controller u can check the data `print_r($userData);`

Comment: @i checked. it fetched all rows, i wil tell what i need is, show user id and then his invoices, then another user id and his invoices ,and so on

Comment: @saleena: yes it will fetch all records, so what u need now? is it fine for u.

Comment: i checked. it fetched all rows, i wil tell what i need is, show user id and then his invoices, then another user id and his invoices ,and so on

Comment: @saleena: yes, and `$userData` contain, userid and its invoices .... and so on it will return result like `array('1'=>array('invoicedata1','invoicedata2'))` now u need to use foreach loop for print values

Comment: i want each user's invoices together,its not getting like that......user1- invoices,user-2-invoices

Comment: @devpro-now the result is correct.. can you explain hw you group each user's data? just to know

Comment: i just store all data against each user into a new array `$userData[$value['inv_userid']][]` somthing like GROUP with userid by using php @saleena

Comment: $userData[$value['inv_userid']][]=$value in this how the correct value of that user assigned? each user id is different,then how this function recognized the values of each user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126788/discussion-between-saleena-and-devpro).